# Parsing http response in nodejs

Tags: node.js, xml, amazon-web-services, parsing, aws-lambda

I am trying a simple parsing of the following to capture the NewCaseId but have been unsuccessful in using DOMParser and xpath.

I've created a lambda function that hits an endpoint and successfully returns a raw response as such:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://<companyname>/<PlatformServices>/GeneralRequest">&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?&gt;
&lt;Response&gt;
  &lt;Case Status="Success" Id="75ba8279-579b-42b6-9c1f-1184f1e076ae" NewCaseId="13825964-8931-4eb5-b60b-f519dbe3ea9c"&gt;
    &lt;InsuranceCaseID&gt;LAMBDA TEST&lt;/InsuranceCaseID&gt;
  &lt;/Case&gt;
&lt;/Response&gt;</string>
```

I have the following code snippet in my lambda function (code snippet has been simplified):

```
  const textValue = await response.text();
  
  const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(textValue);
  console.log(`doc : ` + doc);

  const select = useNamespaces({ vpc: 'http://<companyname>/PlatformServices/GeneralRequest' });

  const xml = select('//vpc:string/text()', doc)[0].nodeValue;      
  const doc2 = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xml, 'text/xml');
  
  console.log(`doc2 : ` + doc2);

  const xml2 = select('/Response/Case', doc2);
  console.log(`xml2 : ` + xml2);
```

This breaks down the xml to just

```xml
<Case Status="Success" Id="75ba8279-579b-42b6-9c1f-1184f1e076ae" NewCaseId="13825964-8931-4eb5-b60b-f519dbe3ea9c">
    <InsuranceCaseID>LAMBDA TEST #2</InsuranceCaseID>
  </Case>
```

But the struggle is extracting the NewCaseId. Does any one have an idea? (Also, breaking it down seems quite convoluted so any ideas there will be most helpful. Even if using other packages such as xml2js or xml-js)

The fetch is done with node-fetch'

I'm new to nodejs and Lambdas so am still learning.

Comment: Without a reproducible example it's hard to help, but are you looking for `item.getAttribute('NewCaseId')`? For example used like this `Array.from(xml2.childNodes).map(item => item.getAttribute('NewCaseId'))`?

Comment: Thanks for your response @PawelKam. I'd include more code but am restricted of what I can include due to my corporation privacy restrictions. Is there something specific you are looking for? I'll provide more details if I can

Comment: Further to @PawelKam's suggestion, I get the following error: `TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))`

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible the contents of the `xml` variable contains html entities (`&lt;` and `&gt;`) instead of literal characters (`<` and `>`)? If so, then `parseFromString(xml...)` won't work the way you want it to.

Comment: You are absolutely correct in your question. The original response is as follows:  

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://<companyname>/PlatformServices/GeneralRequest">&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?&gt;
&lt;Response&gt;
  &lt;Case Status="Success" Id="75ba8279-579b-42b6-9c1f-1184f1e076ae" NewCaseId="f5f8ebe9-d34d-409b-8fad-101d348b84ed"&gt;
    &lt;InsuranceCaseID&gt;LAMBDA TEST &lt;/InsuranceCaseID&gt;
  &lt;/Case&gt;
&lt;/Response&gt;</string>`

Comment: How would I parse this? Would I have to decode it first?

Comment: Yes, I think you'll have to decode it first. Maybe try simple string substitution first just to make sure that's what's going on. If that works, then we can find a proper decode method. I suggest this because it seems proper html decoding is ... not straightforward in nodejs.